# How to set initial data (not test data) in Symfony with doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I am new to learning Symfony, (Symfony 4.1.6) and can't figure this out.

I have a database, and it contains a lot of tables for populating html `select` type inputs.  they are in the database to ensure Foreign Key constraints in other records.

Is there a way to "add" this data to the database and track it? (via git) or should I resort to keeping an SQL file of just the "inserts"

I have looked at Fixtures but they seem to be mostly for dummy data.  I want to insert real data.  What is the "best practice" if any to do this?

****UPDATE****
I should add that the development of this project started outside Symfony, and so the database had already been manually created with a handful of records.  I used `bin/console doctrine:mapping:import 'App\Entity' annotation --path=src/Entity` to build the entities.

Is there a similar way to "suck" the few records out of the db as well?

Maybe I just need to manually add the SQL insert statements to the first (or second) migrate file.

Comment: Upon further reading and inspection of fixtures, I see they are setup as "dev" environment only - and truly not for production use.  I am leaning towards migrations as this seems to make to the most sense.  I am hoping there might be an "automagic" way to generate this though.

Comment: Migrations make diff between your entities and current db layout, and auto generate migration class upon this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In symfony, working with production database, generaly based on creating and executing migrations thanks to `DoctrineMigrationBundle`.

Always when you make some changes in entity, you need to update database layout. You do this by creating migration by command `doctrine:migrations:diff`, review migration class carefully and after that execute it on production server with command `doctrine:migrations:migrate`. This is about database schema.

In turn, when you need to insert, delete or update dome predefined data in database, you could create empty migration class by `doctrine:migrations:generate` and fill with whatever you want. Some examples are:
- Write raw sql queries and execute - this is the easiest way, good for simple data
- Create entities and persist by entity manager
- Load database fixtures - this is the most complex solution.

In this way you do not lost data already stored in production database when you will upgrade your app.

More details in DoctrineMigrationsBundle docs: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html and also DoctrineFixturesBundle docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

Comment: I think this is the answer

Comment: building my own `INSERT INTO ...` statements in `src/Migrations/Version.....php` was the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Fixtures are good for this use-case as well, but be aware not to accidentally overwrite anything.

If you only need to populate these once, migrations are a good option. (You should be using that anyway to manage schema changes.) 
For example, I almost always use a migration to insert admin users and some other really "fixed" data.

Comment: how do you get migrations to "capture" data, not just schema changes? This sounds more appropriate to me.

Comment: Just write SQL like you normally would. Migrations will help you with tracking what is installed, and what is not.

Comment: You could also consider ContainerAware migrations https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're looking for https://phinx.org/ or something like that ?

edit : http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#inserting-data